# Does the usage of "on" depend on the noun that follows?

Tags: prepositions

> That dish **is** no longer **on** the menu.

> His name **was on** the list.

> I **have** the movie **on** DVD.

> I sometimes go **to work on** a bus.

> All shoes **are on** sale,

> The band **is** currently **on** tour.

If I want to use *on*, do I have to look at the verb or auxiliary verb that I used before *on*, or at the nouns or objects that I'm going to use after *on*?

Comment: _On_ has many meanings; you use it if it conveys the meaning you want. In some cases, _on_ is part of a _stock_ phrase, like _on sale_. I could say "They have good stuff on sale." and _on_ would be correct, but not because the verb is _be_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes the preposition is licensed by the preceding verb, sometimes by the preposition's object, sometimes by both.

Trying to come up with rules governing the choice of preposition is hopeless. There are, to be sure, patterns; but every pattern has many exceptions, and you have no way of knowing whether a particular usage is regular or exceptional except by looking it up in a dictionary or corpus.

For instance: *That dish is no longer **on** the menu* and *His name was **on** the list* exhibit a pattern of using *on* with items which are members of linear sets. You might from this predict, correctly, *This building has been put **on** the register of Historic Places* and *I couldn't find his name **on** the ballot*. But you would come a cropper if you extended this prediction to <sup>✲</sup>*You may find that word **on** any dictionary* or *Try looking for his name **on** the index*.

Almost everything about prepositions is idiomatic, governed not by *a priori* meaning but by historical contingency.

Comment: I can, of course, decide arbitrarily whether to say *"Throw another chair-leg **on** the fire"* or *"Throw another chair-leg **in** the fire"*. But if metaphorically praising your performance, I can't say *"Wow! You're **in** fire today!"*.